# Web applications - combine or separate?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, master-pages, extranet

For our company I'm creating a big Extranet website which will feature a set of sub-applications. I'm a bit puzzled by what should be the right setup of the solution and projects.

I have one web application that we call the Portal. It contains the authentication/authorization classes, masterpages, navigation/url routing classes and theme definitions. It will also contain some basic overviews for our customers to get a quick idea of their project status.

In the coming year we are going to develop and integrate more applications with the portal. Think of it as detailed overviews and tools called Feature A, B and C. Over the years we will improve these applications and release new versions. These web applications should fit into the navigation of the Portal seamlessly. I'd like them to reuse the masterpages and themes.

What is the proper way to setup this solution?
How can I tie the applications together, re-use the master pages and keep it maintainable?
How can I share certain webcontrols (ASCX) in a proper way?
We are using TFS, perhaps any branching/merging ideas?

**Edit:**
I'd like to create it in ASP.Net WebForms, we have the most experience in that area. But basically we can use anything, we've got the webserver under our own control (as long as it is Microsoft oriented, not switching to php or something like that :))

Comment: Any specific framework you want to use? Webforms, asp.net mvc, anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`What is the proper way to setup this solution?`

The proper way... There are so many.  I have seen a lot of applications, and a lot of **different** setups (a lot of which that I would deem "proper").  What you're really asking is for the best way for your situation.

Because you're building a portal, you'll have the luxury of feature separation which will help you as you develop additional features for your application.

I would setup a single website with a separate folder for each feature.  Making it a single website will allow all features to share the same masterpages, usercontrols, and configuration file - without having to do anything special.  (On that note, I would put all your master pages in a folder by themselves, and create another folder for your usercontrols).

`How can I tie the applications together, re-use the master pages and keep it maintainable?`

Again... folders are the best option here.  Folders will help separate each feature, making the application easy to manage.

`How can I share certain webcontrols (ASCX) in a proper way?`

First of all, ascx files are not webcontrols.  They are usercontrols.  WebControl is a class for creating server controls that reside in a separate assembly.  Regarding usercontrols, as I said above, if you put them in a separate folder, they're always in one place and available throughout the application.

`We are using TFS, perhaps any branching/merging ideas?`

There really isn't anything special you need to do here.  There are a lot of different paths you can take regarding branching:

- One is to create a branch for every release.
- Another is to create a branch for every new feature you add (in your case, this is pretty much the same as the first option).
- Yet another is to create a branch for each developer.

When I decide how I am going to branch my code, I think about what will protect me the most.  In your case, you need to plan for bug fixes in between feature releases so maybe one branch after each release makes the most sense (call it your dev branch).  Given the separation of features, though, one feature may not effect the rest of the application.  You may not need this kind of branching to be safe.

Comment: Too much branching and you will get into trouble. One branch for every release should be enough. New features should be developed in trunk (as long as they are not too big or experimental). Branch for a developer is something I would want to see (don't go there)...

Answer (score 2):

As Brian says when making an API public you should commit to it as much as possible, which means it should change as little as possible after the initial release. However to make something that stable requires lots of effort up front so if you aren't ready to commit to the API you should instead internalize it as much as possible and for that reason you might want to combine things more than separating them.

However, I'm not going to suggest an architecture that fits your application based on a 5 paragraph description. What you need to do is to weight pros and cons of having a few big projects vs. having a bunch of loosely coupled small projects. I mean, the more planning you do up front, the easier you will have it down the line, provided you stick with the plan.

So contrary to Brians answer, I wouldn't recommend you make your entire system "as loosly coupled as possible", only that you make it as loosly coupled as it needs to be. ;) Loosely coupled code can cause as much trouble as tightly coupled code, if you are abusing it.

**See:**
 1. [What is better, many small assemblies, or one big assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568780/what-is-better-many-small-assemblies-or-one-big-assembly)
 2. [Specific down-sides to many-‘small’-assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192004/specific-down-sides-to-many-small-assemblies)

In the end, only you know how much you want to focus on each of the "...bilities", maintainability, extensibility, reliability etc. So get your priorities and goals straight and plan accordingly.

Regarding branching strategies you could read the [TFS Branching Guideline 2.0](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSBranchingGuideII) which have a good introduction to various branching strategies ranging from basic to advanced. Even if you don't use TFS this is a good guide to read (I use SVN at the moment). Since I currently work in small teams with 1-4 devs, I tend to use a strategy that is between basic and standard. Not that I'm recommending this for you, but that whats works best for our team.

As for sharing code between projects. In SVN we can use "[externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.externals.html)" which means that the shared file will appear in several folders so when you change one copy and commit the change to svn, all the other copies will be updated on the next svn update. However, I can't remember if TFS have something similar.

**Note:** Beware of externals in SVN... they can cause... problems. ;)

My advice is to try to avoid sharing aspx, ascx and master pages as much as possible. It usually hurts a lot more than it helps. Instead try to use inheritance or other alternatives to achieve your goal.

ASP.NET MVC 2.0 has a concept called "Areas" where you build subsections of an application in isolation from the rest. As far as I know these areas can be maintained in separate projects from the "main" application. It sounds a lot like what you are requesting so maybe you should look into that.

Hope it makes sense. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at making your system as *loosely coupled* as possible. As/when you add more applications, your website will become less and less reliable (since no component will be up 100% of the time, combining these will reduce your overall reliability). So you should build your system to cater for the non-major services being down (I believe the Amazon homepage, for example, has 100-ish services contributing to it, and as such it's built to be fault-tolerant)

Your APIs between services should remain as stable as possible, such that the implementations can change without breaking the coupling. You should also investigate automated testing of this at the web level (perhaps [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or similar?) since testing the individual services will give you little coverage re the overall behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it useful to look at implementing a custom [VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx).  On my last project we had multiple ASP.NET sites which needed to share theme files (master pages, user controls, images, style sheets) so I created a VirtualPathProvider which allowed us to map a virtual folder (e.g. /Themes) to any physical folder on the hard drive (e.g. C:\Shared\SiteThemes).

It's not trivial but didn't take too long and hasn't caused any problems.  Incidentally it turned out to be a great way to overcome the maximum component limit in WiX...  Note that you can't precompile sites that use a VirtualPathProvider.

Answer (score 1):

Use MVC Concepts from now. they give more extendability and flexibility for a robust applications.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at using SharePoint.  It's a pretty decent platform for ASP.NET application delivery, particularly if they coexist in an intranet environment; it gives you a lot of stuff for free.

Of course, it has very rough elbows, so to speak, so proceed with caution.

Comment: Funny fact: we first approached this project with SharePoint, however because of our lack of SharePoint expertise, complex site built-up, limited globalization options and the massive amount of custom code we would introduce, we stopped the effort.

Comment: Yeah.  SharePoint is a PITA - the problem is that it's the best there is, which is most unfortunate.  The project you describe really sounds like its sweet spot, as un-sweet as it may be.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think of the applications as seperate but as modules of the overall portal.

I would recommend you look into MEF as this would seem to be a perfect fit.

http://blogs.msdn.com/hammett/archive/2009/04/23/mef-and-asp-net-mvc-sample.aspx